# Can AJAX be loaded without using span or div?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I don't know how to explain this well but I will try. An extra DIV used for calling data via AJAX is ruining the style. Let me explain this with proper examples with what is working and what is giving error.

Working Code (Lets label it Code 1)

```
<div class="levelOne">
    <div class="levelTwo">Elements in Level 2</div>
    <div class="levelTwo">Elements in Level 2</div>
    <div class="levelTwo">Elements in Level 2</div>
    <div class="level2">Elements in Level 2</div>
<div>
```

The above code is working fine. But when I want to fetch the Level 2 elements via AJAX that's where the problem starts because I need to have one DIV element (let's call it `subLevel`) on which Level 2 elements will be called.

Say for example: (Lets label it Code 2)

```
<div class="levelOne">
    <div class="subLevel"></div>
</div>

<script>
    $(".subLevel").load("processes/cards.php").fadeIn("slow");
</script>
```

Where `cards.php` contains code from Code 1 above. This disrupts the way the elements appear. Before the cards (elements) appeared overlapping each other but now it appears from top to bottom. I also tried this without AJAX where I simply put Level 2 DIV elements inside `subLevel` DIV directly to perform the same thing that I was getting via AJAX and I found that I got the same result. That is why I came to the conclusion that unless the `subLevel` DIV is added the level 2 elements are working fine and when added it's not.

But I also need this sub level DIV to fetch AJAX value. I also tried using `span` instead of `subLevel` DIV but no luck, same result. What do I do?

**Screenshots:**

When things are working without the `subLevel` (you can see the cards overlapping each other perfectly, like Tinder)

[image]

When things are not working with the `subLevel` DIV (you can see the overlapping is gone and cards are aligned top to bottom which I don't want)

[image]

Comment: Where exactly you want to add the image from Ajax?

Comment: I want to have a solution so that the extra subLevel DIV I used for fetching data via ajax does not destroys the normal styling. It should only be that for to fetch data via ajax but should not affect the flow of level 2 elements.

Comment: This has nothing to do with making `AJAX` requests but rather your `HTML` and `CSS` styles.